# How to get the prediction value in LSTM model?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

This model is trying to classify the emails whether they are spam or ham.

The training is finished, but how should I input the new email text and get the value that can tell me if the email is spam or ham ?

This is the example code in the text book:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
# prediction on test data

predicted_blstm=model.predict(test_data)
predicted_blstm

# model evaluation

from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score

precision, recall, fscore, support = score(labels_test, predicted_blstm.round())

print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
print('fscore: {}'.format(fscore))
print('support: {}'.format(support))

print("############################")

print(sklearn.metrics.classification_report(labels_test, predicted_blstm.round()))
```

and the result:

```
precision: [0.98782961 0.95348837]
recall: [0.99387755 0.91111111]
fscore: [0.99084435 0.93181818]
support: [980 135]
############################
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      0.99      0.99       980
           1       0.95      0.91      0.93       135

   micro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      1115
   macro avg       0.97      0.95      0.96      1115
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      1115
 samples avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      1115
```

I had tested the code

> mode.predict()

but the result is like:

```
array([[9.9973804e-01, 2.6198191e-04],
       [9.9988401e-01, 1.1600493e-04],
       [9.9996233e-01, 3.7628190e-05],
       [9.9998081e-01, 1.9162568e-05],
       [9.9998498e-01, 1.5043216e-05],
       [9.9907982e-01, 9.2014833e-04],
       ...
       [9.9996233e-01, 3.7628190e-05],
       [9.9996233e-01, 3.7628190e-05]], dtype=float32)
```

What does this number means ?
Can I get the answer from this array by showing the message "spam" or "ham" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the features in your train and test data, but if your model is trained only on the email text feature, then you could the following:

1) Convert the email text, for example "This is the email I want to test", into a vector using the vectorizer used on the training data.

2) If your vector is stored in a variable 'vec'. Then you can predict if the email is ham or spam using

```
prediction = model.predict(vec)
```

The varaible 'prediction' will hold your answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. I have tested this code, but the result gived me an array like [[9.9973804e-01, 2.6198191e-04]..., what does this number means ?